# Is it possible to create a stored procedure that references .sql files?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 5 separate scripts, each a few hundred lines long, which create 5 different tables. I want to create a stored procedure that runs through all of these scripts. The way I am familiar with making a stored procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
AS
sql_statement1
GO
sql_statement2
GO
sql_statement3
GO
sql_statement4
GO
sql_statement5
GO;
```

The issue with this approach is that I update these queries often, and it would seem easier if I could create a stored procedure that points to the sql files rather than having to update the stored procedure each time I have an update. Especially when I have to sift through the 1000 lines of code to update one of the five scripts.

I am wondering if there is an approach that would make it easier to update the stored procedure or to have the procedure point to the final sql files. I haven't had much luck finding content about this online.

Comment: No, a stored procedure can't use SQL contained in a file. Also, a Stored Procedure can't contain batch separators as you have in your example.

Comment: Make five procedures and put the logic of your files in them, one by one. Then make a sixth procedure that calls the other five.

Comment: You may find that using SQL VIEWS or Stored Procedures with embedded SQL statements to be the more appropriate way.

Comment: You should have noticed by now that tsql has no functionality to access resources outside of the database engine. It is simply not designed to do this. One can ask why you think this is something suited to tsql (and a stored procedure) - but that is a larger discussion. Batch scripting using the tool of your choice can do this quite easily - which seems like a better approach. Perhaps [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017)?